# How to build counts filled matrix in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, frequency, crosstab

I have working on a analytics project using R. As a part of data preparation module I got stuck up with a specific task. I have a categorical column and a response variable as shown: 
[image: Pic1].

I need to construct sequential fills as below. It should be constructed as shown: 
[image: Pic2]

The logic is as follows :
Consider step =3. From the actual data consider first 3 rows a,b,c and yes/no column has one 'Yes'. So the respective values of a,b,c,d,e,f in the resultant matrix is filled as 1,1,1,0,0,0 with Yes. The next step has b,c,b, so the resultant matrix is filled as 0,2,1,0,0,0 with Yes. This process should be repeated until the last sequence in the source data.

Is there any possibility of constructing the above. Can anyone please help on building this logic to construct the above resultant matrix using R.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit lost how you achieved this pattern, why isn't the 'e' column 0,0,0,1,2,1? Where is the two coming from?

Comment: It would be nice if you could supply the example data as text, and not image.

Comment: Hi @SCDCE thanks for your response. I am filling  the sequences row-wise. The second sequence has b repeated twice. So I marked it as 2 times. Please let me know if you need further clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rollapply` from zoo with `table` and `any`:

```
library(zoo)

step <- 3

data.frame(
     rollapply(DF$Features, step, table), 
     "Yes/No" = ifelse(rollapply(DF$"Yes/No" == "Yes", step, any), "Yes", "No"),
       check.names = FALSE
)
```

giving:

```
  a b c d e f Yes/No
1 1 1 1 0 0 0    Yes
2 0 2 1 0 0 0    Yes
3 0 1 1 1 0 0     No
4 0 1 0 1 1 0    Yes
5 1 0 0 1 1 0    Yes
6 1 0 0 0 1 1    Yes
```

### Note

The input `DF` in reproducible form:

```
DF <- data.frame(Features = c("a", "b", "c", "b", "d", "e", "a", "f"),
 "Yes/No" = c("No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No"), 
  check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: thanks a lot sir for taking your time.. It worked :)